# 105 R7000 front derailleur with 105 5800 crankset

Tags: shimano, compatibility, derailleur-front

I was thinking of upgrading my Tiagra derailleur with new 105 FD-R7000, but then I read that it might not be compatible with my 105 5800 crankset because the new R7000 crankset has different spacing between chainrings. Will I have a problem if I upgrade to a R7000 front derailleur with 5800 crankset?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You also need to check that your front shifter (105 5800 or Tiagra 4700?) is compatible with the R7000 front derailleur.

Comment: all road front shiftters with double chainrings are compatable i guess.

Comment: I've got the new 105 R7000 front derailleur running on a Tiagra crankset...works fine...in fact it works great. I'd definitely recommend the new 105 FD as an upgrade, the new mechanism design gives super smooth shifting.

Comment: @SimonPitchforth FWIW, I just built up a bike with an FD-R7000 front derailleur that has a Sora FC-3550 compact crankset in place until the new 105 crankset arrives from ProBikeKit.  It shifts so badly up front with horrible chain suck that I'm not about to ride the bike until the proper crankset arrives.  There **are** limits to how far you can push Shimano compatibility...

Answer (score 11):

Shimano lists the FD-R7000 front derailleur as compatible with the FC-5800 crankset in their [products compatibility information](http://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com/3.7), but the R7000 crankset wont be compatible with the old derailleur.
[image]

Comment: what is the meaning of colors in this chart? blue, orange ?

Comment: @UmutBirey Orange means the component is discontinued and blue means its a new product.

Comment: Nice answer with reference doc. Can you add a link to the current location of that chart?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same exact combination, and it doesn't work flawlessly. Don't recomend to use it.

Comment: Can you eloborate why to make this a valuable answer?

Comment: Welcome to the site - could you please clarify, does it work but poorly, or works with some slight problems?  What are the flaws you're experiencing ?

Comment: Agree, currently this is not an answer. Without the details, it is closer to an opinion. Please add what issue you are experiencing to add value to it. It could even be that you may have a question here? Your combination does not work flawlessly, so what can you adjust to fix that?